# PointCloud2 exists, but NO Octomap in /move_group/monitored_planning_scene!

Tags: moveit, hardware, octomap, ros-kinetic, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 on a Huawei Matebook-x, with kernel 4.15.0-91-generic. ROS distro: kinetic and version 1.12.14. Gazebo 7.

My issue is exactly the same as [this one](https://answers.ros.org/question/213368/problem-with-moveit-perception/) from 5 years ago, but that question is never answered.

I added 3D perception to MoveIt following [Perception Pipeline Tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/perception_pipeline/perception_pipeline_tutorial.html).

Content of `niryo_one_moveit_config/config/sensors_3d.yaml` :

```
sensors:
  - filtered_cloud_topic: filtered_cloud
    max_range: 5.0
    max_update_rate: 1.0
    padding_offset: 0.1
    padding_scale: 1.0
    point_cloud_topic: /camera/depth/points
    point_subsample: 1
    sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
```

Content of `niryo_one_moveit_config/launch/sensor_manager.launch.xml`:

```
<launch>

  <!-- This file makes it easy to include the settings for sensor managers -->

  <!-- Params for 3D sensors config -->
  <rosparam command="load" file="$(find niryo_one_moveit_config)/config/sensors_3d.yaml" />

  <!-- Params for the octomap monitor -->
  <!-- <param name="octomap_frame" type="string" value="some frame in which the robot moves" /> -->
  <param name="octomap_resolution" type="double" value="0.025" />
  <param name="max_range" type="double" value="5.0" />

  <!-- Load the robot specific sensor manager; this sets the moveit_sensor_manager ROS parameter -->
  <arg name="moveit_sensor_manager" default="niryo_one" />
  <include file="$(find niryo_one_moveit_config)/launch/$(arg moveit_sensor_manager)_moveit_sensor_manager.launch.xml" />

</launch>
```

It works for me, as shown in the following figure (I used [RealSense plugin](https://github.com/pal-robotics/realsense_gazebo_plugin/tree/kinetic-devel) to simulate the camera).
[image: image description]

And in `/move_group/monitored_planning_scene`, I had actual content in `octomap`:

```
name: "(noname)+"
robot_state: 
  joint_state: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 428
        nsecs: 194000000
      frame_id: "/world"
    name: [joint_1, joint_2, joint_3, joint_4, joint_5, joint_6, gripper_joint, left_clamp_joint,
  left_rod_joint, right_gear_joint, right_clamp_joint, right_rod_joint]
    position: [0.0002741740361669187, -0.005544641035825748, -0.0047824728172924935, -0.004096483894079128, -0.009302052764738278, -0.0036276511038133563, 2.7370436193052683e-06, -4.863704734958674e-06, 3.8067452639012345e-06, 3.5276141945317363e-06, -4.115511588409504e-06, -4.813747795928691e-06]
    velocity: []
    effort: []
  multi_dof_joint_state: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs:         0
      frame_id: "/world"
    joint_names: []
    transforms: []
    twist: []
    wrench: []
  attached_collision_objects: []
  is_diff: False
robot_model_name: "niryo_one"
fixed_frame_transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs:         0
      frame_id: "/world"
    child_frame_id: "/world"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
allowed_collision_matrix: 
  entry_names: []
  entry_values: []
  default_entry_names: []
  default_entry_values: []
link_padding: []
link_scale: []
object_colors: []
world: 
  collision_objects: []
  octomap: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs:         0
      frame_id: "/world"
    origin: 
      position: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
      orientation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
    octomap: 
      header: 
        seq: 0
        stamp: 
          secs: 0
          nsecs:         0
        frame_id: ''
      binary: False
      id: "OcTree"
      resolution: 0.025
      data: [-70, -76, 96, 64, -86, -70, -76, 96, 64, 64, -70, -76, 96, 64, 64, -70, -76, 96, 64, 64, -70, -76, 96, 64, 64, -70, -76, 96, 64, 64, -70, -76, 96, 64, 64, -70, -76, 96, 64, 64, -70, -76, 96, 64, -32, 117, 0, 0, -64, -128, 117, 0, 0, -64, 64, 117, 0, 0, -64, 64, 117, 0, 0, -64, -64, 117, 0, 0, -64, -128, 117, 0, 0, -64, -32, ...]
      is_diff: True
```

However, when tested on hardware, the octomap is not shown. The only difference is the point cloud topic. On hardware, the topic name is `/camera/depth/color/points` (`sensors_3d.yaml` is changed accordingly).
[image: image description]

In `/move_group/monitored_planning_scene`, `octomap` is empty.

```
name: "(noname)+"
robot_state: 
  joint_state: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1594703183
        nsecs: 943662321
      frame_id: "/world"
    name: [joint_1, joint_2, joint_3, joint_4, joint_5, joint_6, gripper_joint, left_clamp_joint,
  left_rod_joint, right_gear_joint, right_clamp_joint, right_rod_joint]
    position: [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0004986655005698084, 0.01689478715930511, -0.00153588974175501, -0.030368728984701332, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity: []
    effort: []
  multi_dof_joint_state: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs:         0
      frame_id: "/world"
    joint_names: []
    transforms: []
    twist: []
    wrench: []
  attached_collision_objects: []
  is_diff: False
robot_model_name: "niryo_one"
fixed_frame_transforms: []
allowed_collision_matrix: 
  entry_names: []
  entry_values: []
  default_entry_names: []
  default_entry_values: []
link_padding: []
link_scale: []
object_colors: []
world: 
  collision_objects: []
  octomap: 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 0
        nsecs:         0
      frame_id: ''
    origin: 
      position: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
      orientation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 0.0
    octomap: 
      header: 
        seq: 0
        stamp: 
          secs: 0
          nsecs:         0
        frame_id: ''
      binary: False
      id: ''
      resolution: 0.0
      data: []
is_diff: True
```

Why is it empty? How can I get it to work?

Edit:
I tried explicitly launching `octomap_server` by adding `niryo_one_moveit_config/launch/octomap_server.launch`  and launched it.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server">
    <param name="resolution" value="0.01" />
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="world" />
    <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
    <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="5.0" />
    <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/color/points" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

It does show Octomap in Rviz, but this Octomap is not in `/move_group/monitored_planning_scene`, so MoveIt will not consider this Octomap for obstacle avoidance.
[image: image description]
Is there a way I can add the Octomap generated by explicitly running `octomap_server` into `/move/group/monitored_planning_scene`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357076/pointcloud2-exists,-but-no-octomap-in-/move_group/monitored_planning_scene!!!!/) by [yiying](https://answers.ros.org/users/52860/yiying/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2020-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answering my own questions for the fourth time on this forum.

With all transforms available, the Octomap is up now. What happened is that not all the joints in the robot were published, even though the missing ones don't affect the tf of the camera link. See [this](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2208) for details.

---

Originally posted by [yiying](https://answers.ros.org/users/52860/yiying/) with karma: 46 on 2020-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0